# Two functions running when only one is supposed to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this code which is supposed to output a different message every 30 seconds and 10 minutes. However when the code every 30 seconds is executed it also executes the one that is supposed to happen every 10 minutes.

```
if (bsec>=600) {
  const embedb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#FF9900')
  .setTitle("Bitcoin block #"+bx.blocks.btc+" was mined")
  .setAuthor('Block mined', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/710590499991322714.png?v=1')
  client.channels.cache.get(`710907679186354358`).send(embedb)
  bx.blocks.btc = bx.blocks.btc+1
  sec = 0
}
if (esec>=30) {
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#3c3c3d')
  .setTitle("Ethereum block #"+bx.blocks.eth+" was mined")
  .setAuthor('Block mined', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/710590499991322714.png?v=1')
  client.channels.cache.get(`710907679186354358`).send(embed)
  bx.blocks.eth = bx.blocks.eth+1
  esec = 0
}
function time() {
  bsec = bsec + 1
  esec = esec + 1
}
setInterval(time,1000)
```

Comment: youre setting sec = 0 when you want to be setting bsec = 0

Comment: Also you want to check the two if's inside the time function, every second. If they are outside they will only get checked once.

Comment: Is it a typo that you have `sec = 0` at the end of the bsec if statement? Should be `bsec = 0`?

Comment: In the first `if`, change `sec` to `bsec`

Comment: Saw that problem. Changed and trying it now.

Comment: I tried that. It stoped doing both of em at the same time, but now the 30 second one runs every 5-10 sec now

Comment: Can you post the updated code you’re running?